# Linking class methods in Cocos2d

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am working on getting a Bullet engine integrated with the rest of a game code.

This consists of making the Player class able to call methods from the BulletCache class without crashing the program (the error reads 'unrecognized selector sent to instance...').

My attempt at integration so far consists of creating a BulletCache object in the Player class' interface e.g.:

```
@interface Player : LevelObject
{
BulletCache *bulletCache;
}
```

But I believed a constructor was needed to further link the two classes. neither classes are immediately related (the Player class is a subclass of several classes,although ultimately a subclass of CCNode), although both are subclasses of CCNode

Could anyone give me any further tips on how to further link the two classes, so the Player class methods can call the BulletCache's methods?

edit: Because I was getting an infinite loop, and the console kept reporting a CCSprite related error in the BulletCache class, I put a breakpoint next to the BulletCache method:

```
CCSpriteFrame* bulletFrame = [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] 
spriteFrameByName:@"bullet1big e0000.png"];
```

And ran "Build & Debug." Upon clicking the 'New Game' button on the mainMenu, the console displayed the loading logs, and then it promptly stopped, the bottom of the console displaying the message:
"GDB: Stopped at breakpoint 1 (hit count: 1) '-init-Line 84' Line 84 is where I put my breakpoint, so it looks like the program is having issues with this code. But it doesn't look incorrect, and the methods should match--I wasn't getting any 'Warning: -spriteFrameByName may not respond to CCSpriteFrame'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure you import BulletCache class .
You also need to initialize the bulletCache in the init method of Player.

Then any instance method of BulletCache class can be called by

```
[bullectCache somemethod]
```

some method needs to be replaced by method in BulletCache class

Comment: thx! how do I go about initializing the bulletCache in the init method? I get the general gist, but what method would I use to initialize, e.g.
-(id)init {
BulletCache* bulletCache = [BulletCache init];
}

I'm not sure what other method I could use to initialize that Class within the Player class.

Comment: if you have declared it as an instance variable then you only have to do bulletCache = [BulletCache init]; in the init or scene method of Player class.

Comment: I added the 
bulletCache = [BulletCache init]; 

method in the Player init method, but it created an infinite loop and crashed the app. Any help?

Comment: try changing [BulletCache init] to [BulletCache node] ... also try debugging using break points and find out where your program is jumping to and from.. then i can help.

Comment: The [BulletCache node]; still produces an infinite loop--this occurs when I click on the 'New Game' on the mainmenu layer. 
I had breakpoints enabled, but I am not sure what I should be looking for. Scanning the console shows the infinite loop, but inbetween the same messages over and over again, here are two messages that might give us a clue:

Assertion failure in -[Bullet initWithSpriteFrame:], /Users/Name/Desktop/Directory/Quexlor/../src/cocos2d-iphone-0.99.4/cocos2d/CCSprite.m:231
a non-NSAssert msg:
cocos2d: CCSpriteFrameCache: Frame 'bullet1big e0000.png' not found

Comment: next time if there is any code related query..please post as an update in the question using formatting..easier to read.. From your code..i believe you are loading some images(CCsprite) in the BulletCache class .try putting a breakpoint there and test if it continues..most probably you are not setting up image loading correctly.